# Как соединить два docker контейнера?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Есть такой сетап docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - app
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
      - database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
```

web.docker:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

    ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    WORKDIR /var/www
```

app.docker:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
        && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Проблема в том, что я не монгу законнектится к базе данных из контейнера app:

```
$ docker exec -it compfixmanager_app_1 bash                                   
root@a42628a029d5:/var/www# php artisan migrate


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.t  
  ables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)                   



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

.env файл (может, я тут напортачил):

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:XT/VwqoBB5yrjIShBMV7W4FRkkZvyyV9Y2oj9aW3yos=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` -- да, определённо напортачили.

Comment: А что нужно? Я просто не понимаю...

Comment: Контейнер с БД нужен, а не локалхост. Каждый контейнер имеет собственный виртуальный сетевой адаптер. [Почитайте, как в Docker Compose работают ссылки](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо, D-side, за ссылку. Чувствую себя теперь глупым. Вот что я понял:

Контейнеры соединяются с помощью дерективы link, которая является массивом вида <имя_контейнера_который_нужно_присоединить>:<хостнейм>. Из этого следует, что нужно было `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` заменить на `DB_HOST=database`

Для тех кто всё еще не вьехал:
Когда запускаете docker-compose up, контейнеры уже соеденены в свою сеть с названием default, в которой можно обратиться к любому контейнеру из любого по его имени. Приведу пример.

Есть 2 контейнера, `postgres` и `adminer`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres: # <= имя контейнера, может быть любым
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  adminer:
    image: 'adminer'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      ADMINER_DESIGN: 'haeckel'
      ADMINER_PLUGINS: 'json-column'
```

Чтобы контейнер adminer мог общаться с postgres ничего дополнительно не нужно делать:
[image: ввод имени хоста]

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего создать сеть внутри докер контейнера, сделаем это в конце файла

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    container_name: web-container
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - proxy.front-network
    links:
      - app
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.docker
    container_name: app-container
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
     networks:
      - proxy.front-network

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
    networks:
      - proxy.front-network


  ###Сети докера - создаются автоматом
networks:
  proxy.front-network:
      driver: bridge
```

И соединим контейнеры в одну сеть, общаться они будут по именам контейнеров. Например база данных будет доступна внутри докер контейнеров по dns-имени

```
database-container
```